# react native app starts only through xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I created a mobile app using react native framework

but it only starts through xcode, if I try to open the app from the iphone it doesn't start

It works fine when I open it through xcode (myapp.xcodeproj), it builds the app on the iphone and then opens it without problems

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The running on device guide from React Native's official site : 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Answer (score 1):

I have also run into this problem today, after upgrading React Native from ~32 to 39.2 (I haven't used it for a long time, that's what I want to say).

I got it fixed by doing the following:

1. Completely disabling the ATS (not sure if it is actually needed as I wanted to run the device locally with no server connected, but at this point I'm too afraid to ask); You can read more about it here: https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/ .
2. **Building** the app before running it (I think this is the main thing).  So I don't remember doing it back in the days, but after I've upgraded, this seems to be the right way to do it:

a) Make sure your phone is connected to the Mac via USB cable

b) In Xcode, go to `Product -> Build for -> Running`

c) Wait for it to build (this will not run the app yet, so be patient)

d) Run the app as usual

I guess that's it! Then you can disconnect your phone. At least it works for me; hope it will help you, too.

**UPD: still doesn't work!**

Later this day, I tried launching my app again and found out that my advice happened to be useless – oddly enough, it didn't solve this problem this time... But no worries – I somehow made it work again!

What I did was go to my AppDelegate.m and change the jsCodeLocation line look just like it looked when I used a lower version of React Native:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

So it works for now... Hope this helps :)

**UPD 2** : don't forget to change the code back when you decide to run it on the Simulator!

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings]      
jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```